# \boxed text as subscript

Tags: amsmath

We already set `\boxed` content as subscript,

[image]

but subscript size not updated,
please advice how to set script size using `\boxed` definitions.

Please find MWE file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fboxsep1pt\arraycolsep1pt\fbox{\m@th$#1$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

the passenger moving with a velocity of +11 m/s, due in part to the walking motion and in part to the train's motion. As  $\boxed{\begin{array}{c}
{PT}\\
{AT}\\
{CT}\\
\end{array}}$ the passenger moving with a velocity of +11 m/s, due in part to the walking motion and in part to the train's motion. As

$$\vec{\mathbf{V}}_{\boxed{\begin{array}{c}
{PT}\\
{AT}\\
{CT}\\
\end{array}}}$$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method with TABstacks:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\SavedStyle}

\renewcommand{\boxed}[1]{\ThisStyle{\fboxsep1pt\fbox{%
  \setstackgap{L}{12\LMpt}\tabbedCenterstack{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

the passenger moving with a velocity of +11 m/s, due in part to the walking 
motion and in part to the train's motion. As  $\boxed{PT\\AT\\CT}$ the 
passenger moving with a velocity of +11 m/s, due in part to the walking 
motion and in part to the train's motion. As
\[
\vec{\mathbf{V}}_{\boxed{PT\\AT\\CT}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\text` from `amsmath`, but you need to help it as regards to the baseline.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{retain-explicit-plus}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\boxedarray}[2][c]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\current@f@size\f@size
  \setlength\fboxsep{1pt}%
  \text{\fbox{\fix@baseline$\begin{array}[#1]{c}#2\end{array}$}}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\fixbaseline}{%
  \ifx\f@size\current@f@size\else\ifx\f@size\sf@size\linespread{0.7}\else\linespread{0.5}\fi\fi
  \selectfont
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The passenger moving with a velocity of \SI{+11}{m/s}, due in part to the 
walking motion and in part to the train's motion. As
$\boxedarray{ PT \\ AT \\ CT }$ 
the passenger moving with a velocity of \SI{+11}{m/s}, due in part to the 
walking motion and in part to the train's motion. As
\[
\vec{\mathbf{V}}_{\boxedarray{ PT \\ AT \\ CT }}
\]

\end{document}
```

For units, as already suggested, use `siunitx` facilities.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I propose a very simple `\subboxed` command, which ensures the maths will be in \scriptstyle  and the value of `\boxsep` is adjusted. In the maintext, I'd simply use a boxed `\Vectorstack` from `stackengine`.

Unrelated to the problem: I used the extensible vector arrows from `esvec` , which look nicer than `\vec` with a bold V.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\newcommand{\subboxed}[1]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}\boxed{\everymath{\scriptstyle}#1}}}

\begin{document}

The passenger moving with a velocity of \SI{+11}{\meter/\second}, due in part to the walking
motion and in part to the train's motion. As $\boxed{\Vectorstack{PT \\ AT \\ CT}}$ the passenger moving with a velocity of \SI{+11}{\meter/\second},
due in part to the walking motion and in part to the train's motion. As
\[\vv{\mathbf{V}}_{\subboxed{\substack{PT\\ AT \\ CT}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may well be too naive but you do not need any complicated `\makeatletter` stuff to box an array.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

The passenger moving with a velocity of \SI{+11}{\meter/\second}, due in part to the walking
motion and in part to the train's motion.  As  $\begin{array}{|@{\,}c@{\,}|}
\hline
{PT}\\
{AT}\\
{CT}\\
\hline
\end{array}$ the passenger moving with a velocity of \SI{+11}{\meter/\second},
due in part to the walking motion and in part to the train's motion. As
\[\vec{\mathbf{V}}_{\begin{array}{|@{\,}c@{\,}|}
\hline
{PT}\\
{AT}\\
{CT}\\
\hline
\end{array}}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course the question is whether the reader wants such boxes. (At least I added `siunitx` and replaced `$$ ... $$` by `\[ ... \]` so this may not be completely pointless.)

Comment: I just post the sample document, my requirement is \boxed content should be subscript controlled in \boxed content itself where we apply "_"

Comment: From the question: “please advice how to set script size using `\boxed` definitions”. I see no script size in the picture.